# wifi icon is missing

Tags: wireless, icons

suddenly, my wifi icon is missing, and showing wired icon instead; but there is no problem in connecting with wireless connection, though I'm not able to connect with wired connection! any help.. here is the screen shot of the problem

[image]

Comment: This is a known bug. Can be fixed by `systemctl restart network-manager`.

Answer (score 1):

try to run this command in your terminal "nm-applet"  with out the quotes. This will launch the network manage interface. So you can check what is going on in your network configuration.

Comment: Thanks but when closing the terminal, it kills the applet. Any sustainable fix ?